# Trying to encrypt an S3 object (video file) using KMS with Lambda code in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-kms

I am trying to encrypt a video file uploaded in S3 using KMS with following Lambda function code. Once encrypted, lambda should put the encrypted file to another s3 bucket.
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong in this code:

```
import boto3
import base64
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Initialize the S3 and KMS clients
    print("event = ", event)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    kms_client = boto3.client('kms')
    
    # Get the S3 event record containing the bucket name and object key
    s3_event = event['Records'][0]['s3']
    bucket_name = s3_event['bucket']['name']
    object_key = s3_event['object']['key']
    target_bucket_name = 'decryptedfiles'
        # Get the encrypted object from S3
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    plaintext_data = response['Body'].read()
    print("the response = ", response)
    print("plaintext_data = ", plaintext_data)
        # Get the KMS key ID used for encryption from the S3 metadata
    kms_key_id = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id']
    print("kms_key_id = ",kms_key_id)
    # Encrypt the data using the KMS key
    encrypted_data = kms_client.encrypt(Plaintext=plaintext_data, KeyId=kms_key_id)['CiphertextBlob']
        
        
        # Upload the encrypted data to the source S3 bucket
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=target_bucket_name, Key=object_key, Body=encrypted_data)
```

This is the error
[image]

Comment: Possibly an issue with your enterprise's outbound network proxy? Try running this code on EC2 or in a Lambda function to see if it works there. Also see [here](https://codetinkering.com/ssl-validation-failed-python/) in case it's helpful.

Comment: Are you positive that the Lambda has access to KMS?

Comment: Aside from the error you are receiving (which seems related to SSL), I can't quite see what you are attempting to do with the code. You seem to have an AWS Lambda file that is triggered by the creation of an object. The Lambda function retrieves the object (which is unlikely to be a video since you are printing the plaintext version of it?), then encrypting it using the KMS key that S3 used to encrypt it? Just checking... Do you know that KMS is automatic and S3 does server-side encryption automatically without requiring you to encrypt the file yourself? Can you tell us why you are doing this?

Comment: Hi @stdunbar, yes Lambda has access to KMS. I have attached the policy to Lambda's execution role

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I was trying to print the Plaintext to check if its empty or actually having any value. I understand that KMS and S3 takes care of encryption but that is just encryption at rest.

Comment: In that case, you can pass `SSECustomerKey` as part of the upload command and it will encrypt the data using "Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Keys". See: [Using server-side encryption with customer-provided keys (SSE-C) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html)